# CSS Gradients & Shadows on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, less

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get the shadows to work on IE...  They are working fine in chrome, safari, and firefox! Does someone have experience with this subject?  I put the site up so you can see the full code and output.

[Test Site](http://3rdrockmarketing.com/CLIENTsites/Website%20Frame/)

I am using lesscss, so maybe that is my issue? I hope not!!!  I am also using the IE CSS3 Fix, [ie-css3.htc](http://fetchak.com/ie-css3/)The code I am using is as follows...  I was attempting to do this without the htc, but with no luck.. at least the htc got my background gradients to work in IE... before it was showing only blue-black, the default Microsoft background gradient colors.

**predefine.less**

```
.RUNgradient(@COLOR: @CLR1){
  @CLRL:lighten(@COLOR, 10%);
  @CLRD:darken(@COLOR, 10%);
  background-color: @CLRL;
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
  background-image: -khtml-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(@CLRL), to(@CLRD));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, @CLRL, @CLRD);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, @CLRL, @CLRD);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, @CLRL), color-stop(100%, @CLRD));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, @CLRL, @CLRD);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, @CLRL, @CLRD);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, @CLRL, @CLRD);
  behavior: url(css/ie-css3.htc);
}
```

**styles.less**

```
div.wrapper{
    width:500px;
    margin:25px auto;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    text-align:center;
    .RUNgradient;
    .RUNshadow;
    p{
        font:24px @HEADERFONT;
        color:#ffffff;
        .RUNtextshadow;
    }
}
```

Filters are the answer! Almost...

For the gradient,

```
 filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr="@CLRL~", EndColorStr="@CLRD~")";
```

And for the shadows,

```
 filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(color="@SCLR~", Direction="@DIR~", Strength="@STR~")";
```

Only thing left is changing the direction in a way to have the shadow visible all around the element, not just to one side.

### Solution

After researching Microsoft Filters, I figured out how to get a similar effect.  The corners are a bit rough for my liking, but this is MUCH closer than before!

This is the shadow filer I used...

```
.RUNshadow(@BLURRING:10px){
    @SCLR:#111111;
    @DIR:225;
    @DIR2:45;
    @DIR3:135;
    @DIR4:315;
    @STR:4;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px @BLURRING #111111;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px @BLURRING #111111;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px @BLURRING #111111;
  filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(color="@SCLR~", Direction="@DIR2~", Strength="@STR~")
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(color="@SCLR~", Direction="@DIR~", Strength="@STR~")
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(color="@SCLR~", Direction="@DIR3~", Strength="@STR~")
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.shadow(color="@SCLR~", Direction="@DIR4~", Strength="@STR~")";
}
```

Comment: Which version(s) of IE do you need to support?

Comment: I would say IE6-IE9...  The actual site this is for is a social network, and we expect the younger generations to use it... So maybe IE6 won't be much of an issue, but just to be safe, I would like to support all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have been pulling my hair out trying to get the shadows to work on IE... They are working fine in chrome, safari, and firefox! Does someone have experience with this subject?"

Yeah, that's normal. Most people don't bother. Remember to ask yourself, [Do Websites Need To Look Exactly The Same In Every Browser?](http://dowebsitesneedtolookexactlythesameineverybrowser.com/)

If you really want this, you'll have to use the [gradient filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847.aspx) for IE. Add the following style to your `RUNgradient` class:

```
filter: ~"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr="@CLRL~", EndColorStr="@CLRD~")";
```

Comment: Perfect! It looks like I was just missing the '~'s from my filters on my first go around... I can get rid of the htc file now.  Only thing left is altering the filters to mimic the basic css3 styles that work on the other browsers... Is there a way to have the drop shadows go all around the elements?  I can only seem to get the direction going one way or the other...    Blurring it is what I think I am looking for.?  I added my shadow filter code to the bottom of my question...

Comment: @NickolasTuttle: If it wasn't clear, the `~` stuff [is necessary](http://lesscss.org/#-escaping) because you're using LESS.

Comment: Oh ok! You helped out HEAPS! Did you happen to know if getting the shadow to go all around the element is possible?

Comment: @Nickolas I don't, actually. I'm not actually sure what you mean about getting it to go all the way around the element. Shouldn't it do that already? I don't have IE installed on this machine to test your code, but you can [play with a demo here](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/filter/Shadow.htm).

Comment: I just figured it out, I was just having trouble with the syntax and how to write it.  I added the solution to the question...

Comment: Actually, still having an issue, The shadow worked fine, but I think since I am running two different filters on the same element, I lose the first effect! Once I add the shadows, the gradient doesn't work! :(

Answer (score 0):

For both of them you can use IE filters.

You can use the [`gradient filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for gradients and the [`Shadow filter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533086%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for shadows. The gradient filter works very well, the shadow filter looks really bad.

You can read in the documentation of the filters how to use them. But if you want to do it automatic you need see how [CSS3 please](http://css3please.com/) is dealing with the filters and convert gradients to IE filter gradients.

Comment: Awesome site! css3please.com...   BUT, it doesn't seem to work very well in IE?

Comment: @NickolasTuttle it seems like they have dropped the IE filter support. (or am I tinking of another site?) However the syntax is the syntax as mentioned by Cody Gray.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these lines to the style tag for making this to work in IE,

**filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#222222'); /* IE6 & IE7 */**

**-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#222222')"; /* IE8 */**

Sample code Snippet:

.ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr
{
background: #222 ;/*when gradients doesn't fill it fills the color*/

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#444, #222);/* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */

background: -moz-linear-gradient(#444, #222);/* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */

background: -o-linear-gradient(#444, #222);/* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */

background: linear-gradient(#444, #222);/* Standard syntax */

filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#222222'); /* IE6 & IE7 */

-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#444444', endColorstr='#222222')"; /* IE8 */

}